# Resize image background keyboard(android)

Tags: android, xml, image

Sorry for my english. I have background image, if keyboard show is resize background image. If keyboard not show evrithing work fine.

sorry obout image i have not 15 reputation

Its normal condition: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7A8H.png)

Its if keyboard is show: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Om5mN.png), background image is resize

Its if i in manifest i write `adjustPan` [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIuj1.png)

Bellow my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="#9a5f35"
            android:layout_height="50dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/edit_profile"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>

               <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/textView1"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                   android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:text="Получить бонус"
                   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                   android:textColor="#fff"
                   android:textSize="20sp" />

               <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/backDd"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/back_arraund" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom" >

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scroll"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                 android:fadingEdge="none" >

               <ImageView
                 android:id="@+id/imageView21"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                 android:src="@drawable/bg_shkaf" />

    </ScrollView>


        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="1) Введите сумму вашего счета"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="20dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="2) Сгенерируйте код"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="20dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="3) Покажите код официанту"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="20dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="4) Получите бонус на счет"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="20dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2" 
                    android:text="Бонусы дают привликательную возможность\nполучть скидки и обменивать их на подарки\nот нашего кафе.Получайте как можно больше\nбонусов, для более ценных подарков"
                    android:textColor="#d2d3ce" 
                    android:textSize="13dp"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView7"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:text="Введите сумму:"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="20dp" />

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1" >
                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/button_radius_get_bonus"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical" >

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                                <EditText
                                    android:id="@+id/summgrn"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                    android:hint="1200"
                                    android:inputType="number"
                                    android:maxLines="1"
                                    android:maxLength="5"
                                     android:background="@null"
                                    android:textColor="#fff"
                                    android:textColorHint="#91623f" >

                                    <requestFocus />
                                </EditText>

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/textView8"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:text="грн."
                                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                                    android:textColor="#fff"
                                    android:textSize="20dp" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView9"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                        android:text="и покажите официанту код"
                        android:textColor="#fff" 
                        />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/registrationsdasdad"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/review_button"
                        android:visibility="invisible" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView102"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                        android:text="Мы очень старались - оцените нас!"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:visibility="invisible" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView212"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:src="@drawable/image_8" />


           <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/generateBonus"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#9a5f35"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Получить"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: so what you need in your layout please specify that also.

Comment: try adding this code to your activity in manifest `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"`

Comment: @RajanBhavsar I need to when I clicked on the input field, the entire content up (picture 1), but the picture that is on the background does not change the size.

Comment: @KaranMer but the content is not correctly raised, the button "send" is the keyboard. Picture 3